# Does PyFirmata support Arduino Nano?

Tags: python, arduino

I have seen a lot of youtube videos and websites using Arduino with Python, but they use Arduino UNO. I want to use Python with Arduino Nano. Before buying Arduino Nano, i would like to know if PyFirmata works with it?

Comment: classic Nano is Uno in a smaller form

Comment: So it works then?